# Google geocode API get LatLng based on zip code

Tags: geocode, zipcode

I have a bunch of portuguese zip codes, which have the format 4000-700, i need to get the latitude and longitude of those zip codes.
I am trying to use this:

```
https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?address=4755-100,PT
```

But Google only returns the lat and lng of the prefix which is 4755, but i need to get the specific lat and lng for the whole zip code.
How can i do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

https://geocode.xyz/4755-100

Portugal x,y z: 41.46952,-8.58580  m

Geocode.xyz

- 444 R MANINHO, SILVEIROS, Portugal 4755-100 » Confidence Score: 0.5
- CARVALHOS PT 4755-100 Portugal
- CARVALHAS PT 4755-100 Portugal
- SILVEIROS PT 4755-100 Portugal

Answer (score 0):

While working on my internship project I found a website for this https://thezipcodes.com/ Create a free account and get the API key from account Section.

```
https://thezipcodes.com/api/v1/search?zipCode={zipCode}&countryCode={2digitCountryCode}&apiKey={apiKey}
```

I found majority of data here.